# медиа-запросы в css перекрывают основную верстку

Tags: css, вёрстка

Пишу адаптив в css без js, получается, что медиа-запрос находится в конце кода и, когда я задаю новый параметр классу в медиа-запросе, параметр меняется на всех брейкпоинтах. 
то есть когда меняю display с block на inline-block в определенном классе, происходит смена на i-b во всех брейкпоинтах+перекрывает основной код

Comment: Что вас удивляет? Так и должно быть. Это css. Можно использовать !important для свойств которые вы не хотите менять, но лучше писать код так, чтобы не пришло это применять.

Comment: а если я из css  перейду в scss - это изменит ситуацию? спасибо!

Comment: Это не другой язык, это постпроцессор. Не знаю, умеет ли он менять области применения, но если да, то это значит, что он просто отменяет ваши измененные стили ниже по тексту скомпилированного css.

Comment: Не должно быть такого. Либо вы не полностью описали проблему и вас не правильно поняли, либо не правильно пишете медиа-запросы. Приведите пример.

Comment: согласен. перечитал вопрос, какая-то ерунда. может быть это среда разработки пакостит? некоторые редакторы типа sublime умеют такое.

Comment: Добавьте свой CSS в вопрос. И поясните, как вы замечаете, что "параметр меняется на всех брейкпоинтах" и "перекрывает основной код" ?

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам пример правильных медиа запросов, правда не под все разрешения, нужные разрешения допишите сами. Разрешения в данных медиа запросах взяты из сетки бутстрап. Основные стили вы пишете в в файле `style.css` стили же для медиа запросов пишите в файл `media.css`. Медиа запросы на то и медиа запросы чтобы перебивать ваши основные стили когда размер экрана на вашем устройстве изменяется на соответсвующее разрешение в медиа запросах.

```
/*==========  Desktop First Method  ==========*/

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1199px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 991px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {

}
```

К примеру в основном файле стилей у вас `div`-у с классом `class` применяется стиль:

```
.class {
    display: block;
}
```

Этот стиль будет действовать для всех тегов с классом `class` до тех пор пока при смене разрешения браузер не встретит в медиа запросах другой стиль для конкретного разрешения, допустим так:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    .class {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

исходя из медиа запросов всем тегам с классом `class` присвоится `display: inline-block;` начиная с разрешения 992px, на разрешениях же ниже 992px будет действовать ваш основной стиль. Для того чтобы стили начинали действовать до определенного разрешения нужно писать их не в `@media (min-width)`, а в `@media (max-width)`.